# How do I get unique email address and retain other fields

Tags: powershell

```
$AllMeetUsers = $null
[array]$AllMeetUsers = gam report meet user all | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select-Object 'actor.email','id.time'

[array]$result = $AllMeetUsers | ForEach-Object {
    $Email = $_.'actor.email'
    If (-not([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Email))) {
        $IDTime = $_.'id.time'
        $FormatIDTime = Get-date($IDTime) -Format("MM-dd-yy")

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Email = $Email
            Time  = $FormatIDTime
        }
    }
}
```

Makes an output table like the following

```
06-07-21 <Email>
09-29-21 <Email>
06-15-21 <Email>
07-12-21 <Email>
07-20-21 <Email>
07-14-21 <Email>
```

I would like to remove the full duplicate email address line.

but this line is not working

```
[array]$result = $result  | Sort-Object -Property email | Select-Object time,email -Unique
```

and

```
[array]$result = $result  | Sort-Object -Property email | Select-Object email -Unique
```

removes the time field while giving me unique email addresses.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: So... Which time/date do you want attached to each distinct email? Earliest, latest, random? All of them?

Comment: Use a Dictionnary `@{}` instead of an array.
$results = @{}
if (-not $results.ContainsKey($Email)) {
  $results.Add($Email, [PSCustomObject]@{
            Email = $Email
            Time  = $FormatIDTime
   })
}

$results.Values

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen interesting point. I want the newest date but I suppose with that answer everything needs a rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Dictionnary `@{}` instead of an array.

```
$results = @{}
if (-not $results.ContainsKey($Email)) {
  $results.Add($Email, [PSCustomObject]@{
            Email = $Email
            Time  = $FormatIDTime
   })
}

$results.Values
```

Answer (score 0):

@MathiasR.Jessen made a good point in the comments and I think my code probably needs a conceptual change. However with the answer I accepted from @Hazrelle above this is how the code came out.

```
$AllMeetUsers = $null
[array]$AllMeetUsers = gam report meet user all | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select-Object 'actor.email','id.time'

$results = @{}
$AllMeetUsers | ForEach-Object {
    $Email = $_.'actor.email'
    if (-not $results.ContainsKey($Email) -and -not([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Email))) {
        $IDTime = $_.'id.time'
        $FormatIDTime = Get-date($IDTime) -Format("MM-dd-yy")

        $results.Add($Email, [PSCustomObject]@{
                Email = $Email
                Time  = $FormatIDTime
            })
    }
}
$results.values
```

For more information.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.1